# how to use Retrofit in Android?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am having a hard time in understanding the Retrofit for my App. I want to use retrofit in it but I am not understanding about it much.

Everthing is very confusing in it. Can any one help me to learn it completely
I dont know how to start and from where to start

***The links I have gone through while trying to learn are as follows :***

- [Using Retrofit 2.0 in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771021/using-retrofit-2-0-in-android)
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html
- http://mobilesiri.com/retrofit-tutorial-android-studio/
- http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/
- https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

Comment: try the official documentation: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: i have tried but not much clearly understanding it

Comment: If you have gone through all those links, and still don't have a clue, you probably should try a different library. Especially the last one is very thorough

Comment: but i want to learn it

Comment: I am flagging this question as being **too broad**. If you have a specific question relating to Retrofit, please use StackOverflow's search functionality to see previous questions or ask a new question that is less broad in nature.

Answer (score 1):

First you have many different library you can use instead of `Retrofit` , the basic one and i think the simplest is `Okhttp` but you have to understand that `Okhttp` is no more supported but still work when you downgrade your `SDKVersion` , and you can use `Volley` to perform the same service as `Retrofit`